# What's the minimum OS to do android in app subscription?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, subscription

I would like implement in-app subscription on my android app, but what's the minimum target to do that ?

2.1 or 2.2 ?

Answer (score 3):

From the Android Developers site (Version 3 is the latest):

> In-app Billing Version 3 is supported on devices running Android 2.2 or higher that have the latest version of the Google Play store installed (a vast majority of active devices).

So the minimum target is 2.2.

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html

Comment: In other words if the targeting device has the old `Market` installed you cannot bind to the `InAppBillingService` and you should treat this situation accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As soon as I know, the subscription "minimum target" is related to the Google Play Store app, and not from your app.
Take a look at:

http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/versions.html#Subs

Answer (score 0):

In-app Billing Version 3 is supported on devices running Android 2.2 or higher that have the latest version of the Google Play store installed.

Source: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview.html#migration

Answer (score 0):

Use the version 2.1 and above since for all the mobile devices are almost higher versions and its good to develop with min version 2.1 & above.

Answer (score 0):

Before deciding the min version for your application you must always check the [platform distribution](http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) on google. For example, I choose not to include 2.2, since it brings unnecessary API legacy issues and too much work for too less benefit. Keep in mind, in-app billing is really complex to get right. The API's are just crazy'ly complex.